# Statistics: Why do we use this convention when computing standard deviation

Tags: statistics

For example, let us say we wanted to find the standard deviation of : $T = \{2,4,4,4,5,5,7,9\}$.

We use this formula to find the variance: $\displaystyle \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \mu)^2 $

However the numbers in this set do not equally occur, so shouldn't a more appropriate formula be:
$\displaystyle  \sum_{i=1}^n p(x_i) (x_i - \mu)^2$

Comment: In the formula, $x_1$ will be $2$, $x_2$ will be $4$, $x_3$ will be $4$, $x_4$ also $4$, $x_5$ and $x_6$ are $5$, and so on. So the formula *does* take into account multiple occurrences.

Comment: Isn't that already covered by your repeating the $4$ and the $5$ (which means $T$ should be considered a sequence and not a set in the first place)?

Comment: Oh I see. Sorry I didn't think they would be equivalent in this case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you are right. Also note that in this case $\mu = \sum_{i=1}^np(x_i)x_i$  which is the expected value.

However, since this is a finite population, it is also valid your first equation. But I prefer to derive the particular case (finite population) from general expressions.

Answer (score 0):

The first formula takes multiple occurences into account. In your example $n=8$ and $x_1=2$, $x_2=x_3=x_4=4$, $x_5=x_6=5$, $x_7=7$ and $x_8=9$. So the sum expands to

$\frac 1 8 \left( (2-\mu)^2+(4-\mu)^2+(4-\mu)^2+(4-\mu)^2+(5-\mu)^2+(5-\mu)^2+(7-\mu)^2+(9-\mu)^2 \right)$.